# my website get crashed when opened on tablet or Ipad

Tags: crash, media-queries

my web site get crashed when it opened in tablet or Ipad i did not know why although i did all the mediaqueries of all different resolution .

the website contains many animations and photos as SVG , I think that the problem is all those resoures is very heavy for the tablet and Ipad micro-processors , my question is there any solution for this problem

this is the link of the web site :
http://www.nineteen-web.fr/~baltha/beta/parallax/

and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

svg images are converted on the fly in bitmap images by the browser.
As you have lots of images, this should cause an overflow during the loading.
You can create a lighter version of the page for mobile or convert the svg images into png and decrease the size and the density of images with a drawing software.

Comment: i did that , but i had the same problem , even the png image is more heavy than svg images , also the web site need to be responsive for this reason i need to work on the same SVG files . for all resolution